# AWS Cognito Respond to New_Password_Required challenge returns "Cannot modify an already provided email"

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

An app that has been working successfully for a couple years has started throwing the following error whenever trying to respond to the NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED challenge with AWS Cognito:

**{"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"Cannot modify an already provided email"}**

I'm sending the below, which all seems to match the docs.

```
{
    "ChallengeName": "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED",
    "ClientId": <client_id>,
    "ChallengeResponses": {
        "userAttributes.email": "test@example.com",
        "NEW_PASSWORD": "testP@55w0rd",
        "USERNAME": "testfake"
    },
    "Session": <session_id>
}
```

Nothing has changed on the front end; is there a configuration change we might have done on the Cognito/AWS side that might cause this error?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I started getting the same error recently. I'm following [Use case 23 Authenticate a user and set new password for a user](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js). After some investigation, I found that it is the `email` attribute in `userAttributes` that's causing `completeNewPasswordChallenge` to throw the error. The `userAttributes` I get from `authenticateUser` used to be an empty object `{}`, but it now looks like this:

```
{ email_verified: 'true', email: 'test@example.com' }
```

I had to delete the `email` attribute (as well as the `email_verified` attribute as shown in the example code in Use case 23) before using the userAttribute for a `completeNewPasswordChallenge`. So my code is now like this:

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {

    ...

    newPasswordRequired: function(userAttributes, requiredAttributes) {
        // the api doesn't accept this field back
        delete userAttributes.email_verified;
        delete userAttributes.email; // <--- add this line

        // store userAttributes on global variable
        sessionUserAttributes = userAttributes;
    }
});

// ... handle new password flow on your app
handleNewPassword(newPassword) {
  cognitoUser.completeNewPasswordChallenge(newPassword, sessionUserAttributes);
}
```

I guess aws changed their api recently, but I haven't found any doc about this change. Even though the value of the `email` attribute is the same as the actual email of the user, it throws the `Cannot modify an already provided email` error if you include it in the request. Deleting it solves the issue.

Comment: This post and answer saved me just now -- I'm in exact same situation. I have no idea what changed, but can confirm that removing email attribute fixed it for me. This is my code:


```
// Removing email attribute; something on AWS side has borked here
export async function completeNewPassword({ user, newPassword, name }) {
  const data = await Auth.completeNewPassword(user, newPassword, {
    name
  });
  return data;
}
```

Comment: This works and it's very irresponsible of AWS to change the API and doesn't publish any updates and logs.

Comment: You my friend are a lifesaver! It's amazing that even now nearly a year later https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js still hasn't updated with this. Really bad documentation.